# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Spring Boot Rest API & VUE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have been getting the following errors when making requests from the frontend(built with vue) to the backend(built with spring boot)

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.app.com/productorder/all' from origin 'http://my.app.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my WebSecurity Class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Value("${cors.allowed-origins}")
    private String allowedOrigins;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))

                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();

    config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"));

    // Move this into properties files
    // make sure to split the array before adding below
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:8080","http://my.app.com", "http://api.app.com"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "UPDATE", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PUT"));

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your request with headers?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Once per request filter  add this

`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Date, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization, From, X-Auth-Token, Request-Id");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");`

Comment: There is no reason to set second filter. The first filter should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CorsConfiguration#setAllowedHeaders(List<String> allowedHeaders)` ([quote](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html)):

> Set the list of headers that a pre-flight request can list as allowed
>   for use during an actual request. The special value "*" allows actual
>   requests to send any header.
>
> A header name is not required to be listed if it is one of:
>   Cache-Control, Content-Language, Expires, Last-Modified, or Pragma.
>
> By default this is not set.

For example, add in the `corsConfigurationSource()` method:

```
config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Authorization", "Accept", "Content-Type"));
```

Notice that you may not need `Authorization` if it isn't used and may need to add other headers as well.